# Composer branche aliasing

Tags: dependencies, composer-php

I have a **package A** (residing in my VCS: GitHub) that only has one branche: *dev-master*. Whenever this package is required by any other package by version constraint **1.*** I want it to be resolved to **dev-master**.

So I put this in my package's composer.json:

```
"extra": {
   "branch-alias": {
        "1.*": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

I tried installing **package B** (which requires *package A -> version 1.*), composer errors out: version 1.* not found.

Why is the alias not working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the alias [the other way around](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md#branch-alias) like this:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```